# Chrome refuses to display iframe, but other browsers do

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, iframe

I want to display a web page within a frame. This page has a redirect in front of it, that navigates to another web page for authentication. This other page doesn't allow its content to be displayed in an iframe which is completely fine for me. If the user is already authenticated, then he will not be redirected to that page. The current behavior is as follows:

If the user is not authenticated, the iframe will show "Refuse to connect" on all browsers, because the request it's redirected to that other web page for authentication.
If the user is already authenticated, the iframe will work on Edge,IE and Firefox, but not on Chrome, where the same message will be displayed.
Can this be solved within the Chrome settings?

The messages are the following:

In incognito mode the iframe looks like this. I blurred the domain name, but the hidden text is the page at which I'm redirected, the one responsible for authentication.

[image: iframe message]

In normal mode (no incognito). Now the hidden text is the domain which I'm trying to reach with my iFrame.

[image: iframe message]